# How can i remove nested or parent object from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I want to remove object using its id, I don't want MongoDB query I
just want to remove object using its id, array stored in the variable,
we can use the javascript function aswell

Example
If I pass `id=ObjectId("5b693e7ddd65ec16a46b7f82")` from this object

```
 [{
     "commentedBy": "test",
     "subComments": {
         "commentedBy": "jaril 2",
         "subComments": {
             "commentedBy": "jaril 3",
             "subComments": {
                 "commentedBy": "jaril 4",
                 "commentId": ObjectId("5b693e7ddd65ec16a46b7f85")
             },
             "commentId": ObjectId("5b693e7ddd65ec16a46b7f84")
         },
         "commentId": ObjectId("5b693e7ddd65ec16a46b7f83")
     },
     "commentId": ObjectId("5b693e7ddd65ec16a46b7f82")
 }]
```

then output should like this

```
[]
```

or if i pass `id=ObjectId("5b693e7ddd65ec16a46b7f83")` then output should this

```
[{
    "commentedBy": "test",
    "commentId": ObjectId("5b693e7ddd65ec16a46b7f82")
}]
```

I use this recursive function for remove comments but it's not removing, because we need to pass key of it

```
async.eachSeries(result[0].comments, function (data, cb) {
    function deleteCommentId(comments) {
        if (comments.commentId.valueOf() == req.body.commentId) {
            delete comments
        }

        if (comments.subComments) {
            deleteCommentId(comments.subComments);
        }

        return comments;
    }

    deleteCommentId(data)
    return cb();
}, function () {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resultFind))
})
```

If I have 500 sub comments then we should we able to any of them with
its id, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How much deep can this object be? Is there any limit to it?

Comment: You need to create a recursive function to achieve this. First in subcomment match the Object If if it is matched then delete the whole object. Otherwise search the child apply the same logic

Comment: @TusharShukla no there is no limit, I have an id of it.

Comment: @DeepakKumar I have created recursive function as well but problem is that, if they pass the very first parent id then it should remove from the array, I have already managed sub comment but not able to do with very first parent :(

Comment: ObjectId("5b693e7ddd65ec16a46b7f82") is a function call with parameter, right?

Comment: @TusharShukla not its autogenerated mongodb id, its not any function

Comment: If it is first parent then remove the whole object. As you mentioned in the requirement. Share your code. Then we can help you

Comment: Show us your current function. This isn't a free code writing service. Objective is to help fix **your code**

Comment: @DeepakKumar okay ill share you give me some time :)

Comment: @DeepakKumar please check, here is the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check if this works well for your requirement?

```
function retComment(commentArray, id) {
    if (commentArray.commentId === id || !commentArray.subComments) {
        return [];
    } else if (commentArray.subComments && commentArray.subComments.commentId === id) {
        return {
            "commentedBy": commentArray.commentedBy,
            "commentId": commentArray.commentId
        }
    } else {
        retComment(commentArray.subComments, id)
    }
}
```

You need to make the initial call like `retComment(commentArray[0], "5b693e7ddd65ec16a46b7f82")`

Comment: thanks for your answer, I got your logic it may work but we can't return [] because array length is not only one, I just put only one object for your understanding,  in the array we have to find from the entire array

Comment: So what you want is, if there is no data, then you need to remove that object and just send you back the object with data. Isn't it?

Comment: Just check my array, objects is array[0], but there is so many comment object and inside it, there are many sub comments, we should able to any of them with id if it is first then it should only pull that comment object from array not other